# How to order both positive and negative values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to create the ordered bar plot in `ggplot2` with both positive and negative values. Here is the data:

```
down    -11
down    -10
down    -9
down    -6
up      6
up      6
up      6
up      6
up      7
up      7
up      8
up      8
up      8
up      8
up      8
up      8
up      8
up      10
up      10
up      11
up      11
up      12
up      14
up      14
up      21
up      21
up      24
```

I have tried this code:

```
ggplot(GO, aes(x = d1, y = order(d2), fill = factor(d1))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity"‌​, position = "identity", width = 0.6)
```

This is not working.

[image]

I would like to order the plot. Can anybody please suggest some code.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: graph<-ggplot(GO,aes(x=d1,y=order(d2),fill=factor(d1)))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",width=0.6) This is not working

Comment: Why do you add your try in comment? Please **edit** your question.

Comment: @nit If you replace `x=d1` with `x=factor(seq_along(d2))` inside `aes(...)`, does that produce the plot you want, modulo labeling?  If it doesn't, please explain in more detail what you actually want.

Comment: @nit Another thing that might be what you wanted is `ggplot(GO,aes(x=factor(seq_along(d2)),ymax=d2,colour=d1))+geom_linerange(ymin=0,size=8)`.  But the thing is *we don't know what you wanted*.  I'm just guessing what you mean by "ordered bar plot with both positive and negative values".  Please be much more specific.  For this sort of question it often helps to show an example picture of the type of plot you want.

Comment: @Pascal Don't bite the newbies, please.  Especially don't blame the newbies for Stack Overflow's broken-as-designed handling of discussion threads.

Comment: @zwol May I completely ignore your recommendation?

Comment: @Pascal If it pleases you to contribute actively in making the site unfriendly and thus worse for everyone, go right ahead.

Comment: @zwol Feel free to judge my contributions to this site according to one comment.

Comment: @Pascal No one is going to read your profile in detail before deciding whether you have ruined their day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350748/plot-a-top-10-style-list-ranking-in-r-based-on-numerical-column-of-dataframe/31351109#31351109) for a similar question. You should set your vector up in the order you want and then use `+scale_y_discrete(limits = yourOrderedData)` and it should plot in your order.