# R ggplot barchat unable to create proper labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a bar chart of the top 10  fortune 500 company over 5 years while displaying company name as labels in the bar chart. I am facing following problems:
1. Each rank on y axis should be equal size and ordered 1 to 10 from top
2. Better display of the company name label.

I found this on question [Plot a 'top 10' style list/ranking in R based on numerical column of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350748/plot-a-top-10-style-list-ranking-in-r-based-on-numerical-column-of-dataframe) but it uses a numeric value to plot.

Here is what i have been able to achieve:

```
# 2011 to 2015 top 10 Fortune 500 companies
year <- c('2015',  '2015',  '2015', '2015', '2015',
          '2015',   '2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', 
          '2014',   '2014', '2014', '2014', '2014', 
          '2014',   '2014', '2014', '2014', '2014',
          '2013',   '2013', '2013', '2013', '2013', 
          '2013',   '2013', '2013', '2013', '2013',
          '2012',   '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012',
          '2012', '2012',   '2012', '2012', '2012',
          '2011',   '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', 
          '2011',   '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011'
          )
rank <- c('1',  '2',    '3',    '4',    '5',    '6',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '10',
          '1',  '2',    '3',    '4',    '5',    '6',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '10',
          '1',  '2',    '3',    '4',    '5',    '6',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '10',
          '1',  '2',    '3',    '4',    '5',    '6',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '10',   
          '1',  '2',    '3',    '4',    '5',    '6',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '10'
        )
companyname <- c('Walmart',  'Exxon Mobil', 'Chevron',  'Berkshire Hathaway',   'Apple',
                 'General Motors',  'Phillips 66',  'General Electrics',    'Ford Motor',   'CVS Health',
                 'Walmart', 'Exxon Mobil',  'Chevron',  'Berkshire Hathaway',   'Apple',
                 'Phillips 66', 'General Motors',   'Ford Motor',   'General Electrics',    'Valero Energy',
                 'Walmart', 'Exxon Mobil',  'Chevron',  'Phillips 66',  'Berkshire Hathaway',
                 'Apple',   'General Motors',   'General Electrics',    'Valero Energy',    'Ford Motor',
                 'Exxon Mobil', 'Walmart',  'Chevron',  'Conoco Phillips',  'General Motors',   
                 'General Electrics',   'Berkshire Hathaway',   'Fannie Mae',   'Ford Motor',   'Hewlett-Packard Company',
                 'Walmart', 'Exxon Mobil',  'Chevron',  'Conoco Phillips',  'Fannie Mae',   
                 'General Electrics',   'Berkshire Hathaway',   'General Motors',   'Bank of America Corporation',
                 'Ford Motor'
)
companysymbol <- c('WMT',  'XOM',   'CVX',  'BRK',  'AAPL', 'GM',   'PSX',  'GE',   'F',    'CVS',
                   'WMT',   'XOM',  'CVX',  'BRK',  'AAPL', 'PSX',  'GM',   'F',    'GE',   'VLO',
                   'WMT',   'XOM',  'CVX',  'PSX',  'BRK',  'AAPL', 'GM',   'GE',   'VLO',  'F',
                   'XOM',   'WMT',  'CVX',  'COP',  'GM',   'GE',   'BRK',  'FNMA', 'F',    'HPQ',
                   'WMT',   'XOM',  'CVX',  'COP',  'FNMA', 'GE',   'BRK',  'GM',   'BAC',  'F'
                 )
fortune500 <- as.data.frame(cbind(year,rank,companyname,companysymbol))

library(ggplot2)

p =  ggplot(fortune500,aes(x = year, y = rank, fill = as.factor(rank), label=(companyname))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text()

# PNG output
png(filename = "result/Fortune500.png")
# Render a barplot
print(p)
dev.off()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ggplot(fortune500,aes(x = year, y = 1, fill = as.factor(rank), label=(companyname))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="stack") +
  geom_text(position="stack", vjust=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what i wanted. Can we reverse the order on y axis to see the top company  on the top. Also how can i format the company names to fit into the box and look pretty.

Comment: You could add `+ scale_y_reverse()`. Define "pretty"?

Comment: Thanks luke. Some company names are so long that they bleed into the other bars. Is it possible to have the text formatted that they fit into their on box and not spill over to the adjoining bar.

Comment: You could reduce the text size (e.g. `size=1` in `geom_text`), you could increase the device size on which the chart is plotted, or you could line-break your strings after a certain number of characters.